# How to create a Button Listener in TKinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a simon says game and am having trouble collecting the users choice to compare against the computer's pattern. I am using four buttons to select the colors that flash on the screen. The problem I am having is my program continues to chug along even if my user hasn't selected a color yet, despite my best efforts to stop it, what can I do to stop the program? Here is my code...

```
    Sequence[]
    PosColors = ["Yellow","Red","Blue","Green"]
    PlayerChoice[]
    Score = 0

    def Game(Sequence, PlayerChoice,Score):
        Score += 1
        PlayerChoice = []
        Number = randint(0,3)
        Sequence.append(PosColors[Number])

        for i in Sequence:
            RunTime = Score * 1000
            Gui.after(1000, blink, rect, SquareCanvas , i)
            RunTime = (Score + 1) * 1000
            Gui.after(2000, blink, rect, SquareCanvas , White)

        X = len(Sequence)
        Index = 0
        Color = " "

        while Color != " ":
            BlueButton.config(command = partial(setSelection,NeonBlue)) 
            RedButton.config(command = partial(setSelection,NeonRed)) 
            YellowButton.config(command = partial(setSelection,NeonYellow))
            GreenButton.config(command = partial(setSelection,NeonGreen))
            Color = getSelection()

        print(Color)

        while Color != " ":
            PlayerTurn(Sequence,PlayerChoice,Score,Index)
            X -= 1
            Index +=1

    def setSelection(Color):
        if Color == NeonBlue:
            return "NeonBlue"
        elif Color == NeonRed:
            return "NeonRed"
        elif Color == NeonGreen:
            return "NeonGreen"
        elif Color == NeonYellow:
            return "NeonYellow"


    def getSelection():
        return TheColor

    def PlayerTurn(Sequence, PlayerChoice,Score,Index):
        PlayerChoice.append(Color)
        print(PlayerChoice)
        Label1.config(text = 'Well done! \nYou advance to the next round!')
```

I am planning on passing this through a checker and to loop it until there is an error but I need to get past this front loop first... I know my logic works as I created it using just lists and the command line before moving on the the graphical portion I just need to know how to get the program to stop to collect the user guess, especially as the length of the pattern gets larger. Originally I had the command function included later where I build my Buttons but this placement seems to get as close as possible to what I am looking for. Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: This is the segment of my code needed to get the user input, I can post all of the code if you would like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to rethink your main program logic. Tkinter is designed such that you should never have your own infinite loop. Tkinter already has an infinite loop -- the `mainloop()` method of the root window. You can't write logic that waits for input from the user. You have to think of the GUI as in a perpetual state of waiting, and you need set up handlers (button callbacks or event bindings) to react to events.

You also need to understand that a button command can't "return" anything. "Can't" is a bit strong since it obviously can, but there's nothing waiting for the result -- no place to return it to.  You need to design your button function such that it sets a global or instance variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input... Would this work if I added an event handler <ButtonClicked> = False then have it set to True when the Color variable doesn't equal " ". Then have the True <ButtonClicked> event allow the program to move forward into the PlayerTurn sequence?

Comment: @Schneemanch: no, I don't think so. I don't think there's a simple fix. Like I said, you need to rethink the main logic. You're going to have to remove all of your while loops, and replace them all within a single call to `mainloop` after  you've configured your buttons to call whatever functions they need to call.